# Do web crawlers read JSP pages inside the WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jsp, seo, web-crawler, bots

I have a webapp that uses jsp pages. I purposely did not put the jsp pages in the WEB-INF 
folder because there is only minimal code in the jsp and because at the time (about 5 years ago) I read that webcrawlers wouldn't find the files inside the WEB-INF folder. Therefore affecting my SEO/Rank/Search Engine Search results.

I also put the jsp file locations in the sitemap.xml file. I'm using tomcat and the site is fully public with no login/security requirements.

So, fast forward to now. My site has a pretty good rank and pretty good search results. Should I move the jsps to the WEB-INF folder? Was my source wrong 5 years ago?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @Jonn Conde  Why can't java/jsp be combined with SEO? The site is written in Java/JSP and the question is related to web crawling (one part of SEO). The only people who can answer these questions is those who understand both. If we move this to an SEO topic they'll have no idea what JSP or WEB-INF is.

Comment: You may find this link useful - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587

Comment: @Jiri I didn't know this existed. You can actually see what the bot sees. Very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you read 5 years ago,still holds true. 
Files under WEB-INF are not directly accessible.

Comment: Its weird that there is so little information on Monetizing/Search Optimization/rank for java developers. Thanks!